# Print a datatable from VF page

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have two apex:datatable in my VF page. I need an option of printing these tables from the VF page. How as renderasPdf work? does it print the whole page or can we render only that datatable? Or should we have the table generated in another vf page and render that page as pdf

Any pointers?

Thanks
Prady

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`renderAs=pdf` renders the entire page. You could make your datatable a custom component and include it in two different VF pages: 1 that is your screen-only page, the other that is a pdf VF page.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. That should be the logical way to go ahead